# Map enum values to class constants

Tags: java, mapstruct

In our code base, we have a lot of pseudo-enums:

```
public final class Target extends PseudoEnum {

  public static final ErrorCode FOO = new ErrorCode(1);
  public static final ErrorCode BAR = new ErrorCode(2);

  private Target(int value) {
    super(value);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use MapStruct to map these pseudo-enums to enum values, and vice versa.

```
public enum Source {
  
  FOO, BAR
}
```

The following doesn't work, since target is not an enum:

```
@Mapper
public interface SourceMapper {

  @ValueMapping(target = "FOO", source = "FOO")
  @ValueMapping(target = "BAR", source = "BAR")
  Target map(Source source);
}
```

The following does work:

```
@Mapper
public interface SourceMapper {

  Map<Source, Target> MAPPING = Map.of(
      Source.FOO, Target.FOO,
      Source.BAR, Target.BAR
  );

  default Target map(Source source) {
    return MAPPING.get(source);
  }
}
```

It has no real interest for me, though, since I end up writing all the mapping code.

Is there a way to have MapStruct automatically map enum values to class constants?

It doesn't look like such a specific use case, but I didn't find any clue in the documentation.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The [javadoc](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/api/org/mapstruct/ValueMapping.html) for `ValueMapping` states that an _enum_ name is a valid argument, but your `target` names are _not_ for enum constants (reflectively, they're accessed differently). You could include a parameter in the `Target` class for the `Source` enum it is being replaced with, then replace any usages in your codebase in order to deprecate the `Target` enum. No more maps or mapstruct, and you could add a static convenience method to `Target` to grab a constant for a provided `Source` parameter.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I clarified my post.

Comment: @Rogue: I can't modify or delete any of the target code. I'm using MapStruct to map  DTO from a webservice to domain objects.

Comment: @Stov same idea then, just reverse it. Have `Source` keep a reference of the `Target` that it replaces. Then add `static Source#findReplacement(Target)` to facilitate the `Target->Source` lookups.

Answer (score 0):

The clarification with what does work is the only way to achieve such a thing. MapStruct allows value mappings from `Enum` to `Enum`, `Enum` to `String` and `String` to `Enum`. Mapping from `Enum` to some arbitrary final field in a class is something that MapStruct does not support.

The best solution is to have a static util class that would do this mapping.

e.g.

```java
public class SourceTargetUtils {

  private final Map<Source, Target> MAPPING = Map.of(
      Source.FOO, Target.FOO,
      Source.BAR, Target.BAR
  );

  public static Target getTarget(Source source) {
    return source == null ? null : MAPPING.get(source);
  }
}
```

Doing it like this you can then use this `SourceTargetUtils` in other mappers.

e.g.

```java
@Mapper(uses = SourceTargetUtils.class)
public interface MyOtherMapper {

    //...
}
```